# How to display table which contain image and other data

Tags: java

Actually i am able to display image or remaining columns but not image +data

this is my code

```
if(rs1.next()){ 

imgLen = rs 1. getString(5);
int len = imgLen.length();  
byte [] rb = new byte[len];  
InputStream readImg = rs1.getBinaryStream(5);  
int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len);    
response.setContentType("text/html"); 
out.print(rs1.getInt(1) + "\t");
out.print(rs1.getString(2) + "\t");
out.print(rs1.getString(3) + "\t");
out.print(rs1.getLong(4) + "\t");

ps.close();  
response.reset();  
response.setContentType("image/jpg");  

response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len);

response.getOutputStream().flush(); 
}
```

Comment: That's nice.  What is your question?

Comment: image is displaying but not data.

Comment: table contains five columns 5th column contains image. first 4 columns data is not displaying.only image is displaying. how to display both?

Comment: Please read abour [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you closely observe your code, you will find that you are doing a `reset` your `response` object.

```
response.reset();
```

This will clear any data that exists in the `buffer` as well as the `status code` and `headers`. That means it will `reset` whatever operation you have done on your `response`, such as, below:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");

out.print(rs1.getInt(1) + "\t"); 
 .
 .
```

And after doing the reset you are only writing image date to the `response` and also setting the `contentType` to `"image/jpg"`. Hence, only image it displayed.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have remove this. response.reset();  Even not coming. it's giving pic symbol not even pic.